# Object reference not set to an instance of an object (VS 2010 - VB)

Tags: vb.net

So here is my code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class ChartOfAccounts

Public dbCon As New MySqlConnection
Public strQuery As String
Public dbCmd As MySqlCommand
Public DR As MySqlDataReader
Public dbAda As MySqlDataAdapter
Public dbTable As DataTable
Public DS As DataSet

Private Sub updateTable()
    strQuery = "SELECT * FROM account_chart"
    Try
        dbAda = New MySqlDataAdapter(strQuery, dbCon)
        dbTable = New DataTable
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        dbAda.Fill(dbTable)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dbTable
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("MySQL Connection Error:" & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Connection Error")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btncoa_save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btncoa_save.Click
Dim AcctName As String
Dim AcctType As String
Dim AcctNormalSide As String
Dim AcctDescription As String
Dim rowCount As Integer
AcctName = txtcoa_name.Text
AcctType = cmbcoa_type.SelectedItem
AcctNormalSide = cmbcoa_normal.SelectedItem
AcctDescription = txtcoa_desc.Text
strQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account_chart WHERE coa_name='" & AcctName & "'"
Try
    dbCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
    rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(dbCmd.ExecuteScalar())
    If rowCount <> 0 Then
        MsgBox("Account name already exists!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Procedure Error")
    Else
        strQuery = "INSERT INTO account_chart(coa_name, coa_type, coa_normal, coa_desc) VALUES('" & AcctName & "','" & AcctType & "','" & _
            AcctNormalSide & "','" & AcctDescription & "')"
        Try
            dbCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
            DR = dbCmd.ExecuteReader()
            DR.Read()
            DR.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("MySQL Procedure Error:" & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Procedure Error")
            DR.Close()
        End Try
        MsgBox("Information added successfully!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Saving to Database")
    End If
    DR.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("MySQL Procedure Error:" & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Procedure Error") 'error message: object reference not set to an instance...
End Try
updateTable()
End Sub
End Class
```

And I am getting an "Object reference not set to instance of an object" error message as indicated whenever I enter the Else statement (I found it out by experimenting with the messagebox messages so I can see when the error message occurs, and it showed up when I am adding an account name that does not exist yet). Data is added to the database but it is showing the other MsgBox (the one showing this error message). I want to get rid of it so that when I add a data to the database, it just shows the message box "added successfully" without the error message. Why is that error occuring?

Comment: You might want to use the debugger to pinpoint the line where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Where is strQuery declared?

Comment: Also, you should learn to use parametrized queries instead of using string concatenation in order to avoid potential SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @Inisheer Sorry I forgot to add. It is declared as public along with the other MySql connection declarations, after the Public Class Form1. I also have Imports.MySql.Data.MySqlClient.

Comment: @user3252763 Ok, so if you're sure, which line exactly throws the exception ?

Comment: I don't see dbCon & dbCmd declared anywhere either.

Comment: @LucMorin MsgBox("MySQL Procedure Error:" & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Procedure Error") in the outermost Try-Catch block.

Comment: @Inisheer I just edited my code above. I have included the MySql declarations.

Comment: @user3252763 that's not the line throwing the exception, this is where you catch it.

Comment: @LucMorin Oh, I'm really sorry. I completely misunderstood your comments. That is what I want to know. The debugger is not showing me anything about the error. The program doesn't die instead it continued saving the account name to the database.

Comment: Wow. I run the program again and this time the error message is not showing up. Everything is fine now. What just happened.

Comment: As an aside, you should not use `ExecuteReader` when performing an INSERT.  You should call `ExecuteNonQuery` instead.